# Running an LM with emmeans and contrasts for many columns in R

Tags: r, loops, lm, emmeans

I'm trying to compare means between treatments using LM for many columns using specific contrasts. When I run each column individually it works just fine but I have over 1000 columns and it isn't feasible to set them all up individually. I am pretty new to R and haven't figured out how to work with loops yet, so any help would be much appreciated.

This is how I set up the contrasts

```
df$GROUP <- factor(df$GROUP, levels = c("TRT1", "TRT2", "TRT3", "TRT4", "TRT5", "TRT6", "TRT7"))
Contrasts <- list(A = c(0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0),
                  B = c(-1, 2, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0),
                  C = c(0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  D = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1),
                  E = c(0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1),
                  F = c(0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1))
```

[This is an example of my data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G35c6.png)

Essentially I need to run this code for every column.

```
lm1 <- lm(CE(12:0) ~ GROUP, data = df)
lsmean <- emmeans(lm1, "GROUP")
contrast(lsmean, Contrasts, adjust = "none")
```

Comment: This is a class `mlm`. So simply do `lm1<-lm(as.matrix(df[-1])~GROUP, data = df)` this will run all the regressions for you

Answer (score 0):

his is a class `mlm`. So simply do:

```
lm1<-lm(as.matrix(df[-1])~GROUP, data = df)
```

this will run all the regressions for you.

For example, using the `iris` dataset:

```
lm(as.matrix(iris[-5])~Species, iris)

Call:
lm(formula = as.matrix(iris[-5]) ~ Species, data = iris)

Coefficients:
                   Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width
(Intercept)         5.006         3.428        1.462         0.246     
Speciesversicolor   0.930        -0.658        2.798         1.080     
Speciesvirginica    1.582        -0.454        4.090         1.780
```

This is similar to running 4 different linear regression models of the variable against the group.

Comment: This was very helpful for analyzing all of the columns. When I run the contrast statement it gives me a averaged results for all of the columns. Is there a way to get a list of the contrasts for each of columns individually?

Comment: @Brandon That means you will have to do a loop. Thought you were trying to avoid the loop

Comment: If a loop works that's fine. I just don't know how to do them.

Comment: You don't need a loop. Just run `emm <- emmeans(model, ~ GROUP | rep.meas); contrast(emm, Contrast, adjust = "none")`

Comment: However, this will result in a set of 6000 contrasts... If you are new to R, maybe it would be better to start with less daunting expectations.

Comment: @RussLenth I will give this a try and see how it works. Thanks

Comment: I'm reconsidering this multivariate approach. Internally, there will be huge storage requirements for this. One matrix f linear functions will be 6000 x 6000 - mostly zeros and mostly the same things repeated 1000 times - plus lots of other smaller arrays, maybe 500MB altogether. I think a loop will be much better. Can you create a vector of your 1000 dependent-variable names, or access them using their indexes?